# Can I override Joomla's date format from within the template folder or its language.ini file?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I know you can change the default date format of Joomla by editing the en-GB.ini file in the languages folder.

Is there anyway to override this by using my templates language file?

I've tried pasting

```
DATE_FORMAT_LC="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC1="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC2="l, d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC3="d F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC4="Y-m-d"
DATE_FORMAT_JS1="y-m-d"
```

Into the language file of my template. Using language bebug shows that the file is being loaded. However, the date format in my front end pages still remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format information for Joomla! is stored in the file `/language/<your_language>/<your_language>.ini`

for `en-GB.ini`, around line 224 (in Joomla! 2.5).

Locally you can override it in (if you like working with the GUI):

**Extensions -> Language Manager -> Overrides**

or in `language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini`

---

**Now if you want to put the override in your template**, try the following:

You create the folder:

`<your_template>/language/overrides`

put inside the file with overrides (eg.) `en-GB.override.ini`

In templateDetails.xml you need to add:

```
<languages>
    <language tag="overrides">language/overrides/en-GB.override.ini</language>
</languages>
```

References:

[How do you change the date format?](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_change_the_date_format?)

[Template language override (COM_CONTENT_ARTICLE_INFO="")](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2566454)